# Compare the two dataframe based on the combination of two column in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have to data frame as shown below.

where df2 is the updated version of df1.

df1:

```
Sector      Plot         Status
SE1         1            UnderConstruction
SE1         2            Constructed
SE1         3            UnderConstruction
SE2         1            Constructed
SE2         2            Constructed
SE2         3            Developed
```

df2:

```
Sector      Plot         Status
SE1         1            Constructed
SE1         2            Constructed
SE1         3            Developed
SE2         1            Constructed
SE2         2            Developed
SE2         3            Developed
SE3         1            Developed
```

from the above I would like to compare above two table and create new table as shown below in pandas.

```
Sector      Plot         NewStatus         PreviousStatus
SE1         1            Constructed       UnderConstruction
SE1         3            Developed         UnderConstruction
SE2         2            Developed         Constructed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with outer join by first 2 columns and then filter out same rows and also rows with misisng values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df2.merge(df1, how='outer', on=['Sector','Plot'], suffixes=('_new','_prev'))
df = df[df['Status_new'].ne(df['Status_prev'])].dropna(subset=['Status_new','Status_prev'])
print (df)
  Sector  Plot   Status_new        Status_prev
0    SE1     1  Constructed  UnderConstruction
2    SE1     3    Developed  UnderConstruction
4    SE2     2    Developed        Constructed
```

You can create function like:

```
def compare(df1, df2, on, comp):
    df = df2.merge(df1, how='outer', on=on, suffixes=('_new','_prev'))
    return (df[df[f'{comp}_new'].ne(df[f'{comp}_prev'])]
                .dropna(subset=[f'{comp}_new',f'{comp}_prev']))


df = compare(df1, df2, ['Sector','Plot'], 'Status')
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert that into function